# Chart.js ignoring stepSize in the first and last step

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

I am trying to draw chart using chart.js. I am unable to set xAxis to have equal steps:

```
var minimal = (new Date(2017, 9, 1, 0, 0)).getTime();
var maximal = (new Date(2018, 9, 1, 0, 0)).getTime();
var step =(maximal - minimal)/12.0;
.......
xAxes: [{
        type: 'linear',
        ticks: {
            min: minimal,  
            max: maximal,  
            fixedStepSize:  step,
            stepSize: step,
            steps: 12,
```

But in final chart, first step have 20 days and last step have 10 days. I want to have steps with equal stepsize:[image]

Any advice here?

Edit: I created JSFiddle with this issue: http://jsfiddle.net/m48soqa4/2/

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with the `ticks.callback`-property, but I'm not too happy with it, feels dirty:

See docs [here](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/labelling.html#creating-custom-tick-formats)

```
ticks: {
    [...],
    callback: function(value, index, values) {
        if(index !== 0 && index !== values.length - 1){
            // Return value only when it's not the first and not the last
            return value;
        }
    }
```